# How to produce data after getting firebase firestore in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to show all of the orders data that I get from firebase to my browser console. Please look at the picture below

[image]

this is the data which get from firebase after written some codes like below in cue.js

```
orders(){
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const dbOrderRef = db.collection('order');
    dbOrderRef.get()
        .then(res => {
            res.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data())
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error', err)
        })
}
```

I have tried to like this below

The instance variable in data

```
ordersData = []
```

then in method

```
this.ordersData = doc.data()
```

but no luck.

What can I do for now to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: please try to add a working codepen /code sandbox example!!

Comment: You can store doc.data() which you got from firebase assign to data variable as an array and in UI display you can use v-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to assign to an `ordersData` Array all the orders received from a Firestore query.

The following should do the trick:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const dbOrderRef = db.collection('order');

let orderArray = [];
dbOrderRef.get()
    .then(res => {
        res.forEach(doc => {
            let orderObj = doc.data();
            orderObj.id = doc.id;
            orderArray.push(orderObj);
        });
        this.ordersData = orderArray;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err)
    })
```

---

Then you can display the `ordersData` array in your template as follows, for example:

```
            <div v-if="ordersData.length">
                <div v-for="order in ordersData">
                    <h5>{{ order.name }}</h5>
                    <p>Price: {{ order.price }}</p>
                    <p>
                     <a @click="openOrderDetail(order.id)">Open order</a>  
                     // Here we show how we can call an openOrderDetail() method passing the Firestore document id of the order.
                     // This would allow, for example to route to a page where you use the order id to query for the order document.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While working with `then`, this keyword used inside the then block refers to the block itself and not the Vue object. The following solution should work as the orders function, in which we save the Vue reference in another variable and use this variable to access ordersData.

```
let _this = this
const db = firebase.firestore();
const dbOrderRef = db.collection('order');
dbOrderRef.get()
    .then(res => {
        res.forEach(doc => {
            _this.ordersData = doc.data();
            console.log(_this.ordersData)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err)
    })
```

Comment: Hello @ParthJawale, note that since the OP is using arrow functions, there should not be any problem of scope, see https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc or https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-arrow-functions/

Comment: Oh, alright!
Always great to learn something new.
Will read up on it.